# could not convert <string> from ‘const char []’ to <class name>

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a problem that conserns the following programs:

```
    class Player {
    public:
      Player(int new_id);
    private:
      string name;
      int id;
     };

     class Team {
        public:
          Team(string new_name);
        private:
          Player* player;
          string name;
        };

        int main()
        {
           Team a("Team1");
        }

        Team::Team(string new_name)
        {
           name=new_name;
           player= new Player[2]{1,2};
         }

        Player::Player(int new_id)
       {
          id=new_id;
       }
```

This program works but when I change it to this:

```
    class Player {
    public:
      Player(string new_name);
    private:
      string name;
      int id;
     };

     class Team {
        public:
          Team(string new_name);
        private:
          Player* player;
          string name;
        };

        int main()
        {
           Team a("Team1");
        }

        Team::Team(string new_name)
        {
           name=new_name;
           player= new Player[2]{"Bob","Tom"};
         }

        Player::Player(string new_name)
       {
          name=new_name;
       }
```

it gives me this error:could not convert ‘"Bob"’ from ‘const char [4]’ to ‘Player’. I do not understand. The only thing that I change is that I use of string instead of int. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "I use of string instead of int", do you intend "string" to mean the general concept of a (null-terminated) sequence of characters, or more specifically a `std::string`? (Relevant because you use string literals in one place and `std::string` in another.)

Comment: I mean std::string

Comment: Then your claim is wrong. You do not use `std::string` instead of `int` in the line that is supposed to construct your `Player`s.

Comment: What do you mean? What do I use?

Comment: The error tells you what the type of `"Bob"` is; it is `const char []` , not `std::string`.

Comment: @JaMiT That's not particularly helpful; intuitively one usually expects a `std::string` to be constructible from a `const char[4]`.

Comment: @JaMiT _"Then your claim is wrong"_ No it isn't; the OP changed the param type in the ctor from `int` to `string`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 The claim involves the word "only". The change of the parameter type is not the *only* change that was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about user-defined conversions, as specified by the C++ standard:

> Conversions       [class.conv]
>
> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and
>   by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined
>   conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 7), for
>   initialization (11.6), and for explicit type conversions (8.4, 8.2.9).

The problem is that:

> ... at most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
>   function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

In your working example:

```
player= new Player[2]{1,2};
```

You have one user-defined conversion taking place here: `int` to `Player` by using `Player`'s constructor that takes an `int` parameter.

But in the other case:

```
player= new Player[2]{"Bob","Tom"};
```

Here, you need two user-defined conversions to happen: a literal char string to a `std::string` using its constructor, and then `Player`'s constructor that takes a `std::string` parameter. Two user-defined conversions are needed here. At most one is allowed by the C++ standard. Fail.

I can only think of two possible workarounds. One is to manually eliminate one of the user-defined conversions:

```
player= new Player[2]{std::string{"Bob"}, std::string{"Tom"}};
```

Now there's only one user-defined conversion left, from a `std::string` to a `Player` using its constructor.

The second workaround is to cheat and make `Player` use a template constructor:

```
class Player {
public:
    template<typename Arg>
    Player(Arg &&arg)
        : name{std::forward<Arg>(arg)}
    {
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    int id;
};
```

This effectively accepts any parameter to `Player`'s constructor, punting one of the user-defined conversions downhill to the string's constructor. One could do some refinements here, I suppose, and make this constructor participate in overload resolution only if the construction of the `std::string` succeeds. That will require more work.

Comment: Are you sure the Player ctor invocation is a "conversion" in this scenario? I'd expect each part of the array initialiser to be, well, an initialiser for `Player`. Perhaps that's not the case.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#22.2 http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2.1

Comment: Ah it's not 17.6.2.1 it's http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.5 so we get copy-initialisation. Kinda surprised by that tbh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in this statement

```
player= new Player[2]{"Bob","Tom"};
```

there are required two user-defined implicit conversions. The first one is to convert a string literal to the type `std::string` and the second one is to convert an object of the type `std::tring` to the type Player. This is not allowed by the C++ Standard.

To avoid the error add one more constructor to the class. For example

```
class Player {
public:
  Player( const std::string &new_name) : name( new_name ) {}
  Player( const char *new_name) : name( new_name ) {}
private:
  string name;
  int id;
 };
```

Or without adding a new constructor you could just write

```
player= new Player[2]{ Player( "Bob" ), Player( "Tom" ) };
```